# How to get value from tables using LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql

This is my structure of tables:
[tables_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa8kB.png)

and there's `tbl_owner`, `tbl_rooms` and `tbl_class`.

How do I get `id_class` and class name from `tbl_class`.

The original source code is like this:

```
SELECT
  clas.id_class,
  clas.class_name
FROM
  tbl_rooms AS room
LEFT JOIN tbl_class AS clas ON room.id_class = clas.id_class
LEFT JOIN tbl_owner AS own ON room.id_owner = own.id_owner
WHERE own.id_owner='1';
```

However, it did not work. Please help me?

Comment: 'it did not work' is not too constructive. What *did* happen? Did you get an error? Did you get an unexpected result? Please post your dataset and expected result

Comment: the existing data in the database do not appear. No table structure drawn in the link I provide.
no description error. only the data does not appear

Comment: The link of table structures is broken.

Comment: no... I have changed the link. please, look again

Comment: The image link to structure worked before it was edited

Comment: https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipNm1GfyjNZKS5UG-K4usqlU7IDBGwWlHPqHhW29

Comment: that the image of tables

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT
    clas.id_class,
    clas.class_name
FROM
    tbl_rooms AS room
    LEFT JOIN tbl_class AS clas ON room.id_class = clas.id_class
    LEFT JOIN tbl_owner AS own ON room.id_owner = own.id_owner
WHERE own.id_owner='1';
```

`Left Join`s and wheres can be a little confusing.

Here you are asking for all rooms and if they have a class return it, it they have an owner return it. Which is done by the `left join`.

Then after getting that info, Your asking to filter the results by `owner = 1`

Given that there were `left join`s used to build this data, you have now said only show the results where both joins matched. Effectively turning the `left join` to an `inner join`.

I would take away the where clause and check the join conditions are producing results you expect first, then start to allow the where to narrow the result set.

The correct way to check if a left join is a condition is `(own.id_owner='1') OR (own.id_owner is null)`

That will bring back all owner = 1 and all unknown owners

Comment: Then the right source code like what?  I am still confused to write it

Comment: No idea, your link doesnt work and you dont say what info you want from the query. I suggest using SQL fiddle to give us a real data set

Comment: take off the where and do `select * from` do the results look correct ?

Comment: Actually i wanna show the class id and name class accordance  to id owner. For the structure photo, the table is in this following link https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipNm1GfyjNZKS5UG-K4usqlU7IDBGwWlHPqHhW29